# Is it possible to tweak the settings so it automatically places quotations when using System.out.println()?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using java on Intellij and I wonder if it is possible to make it so that it automatically places quotations System.out.println(**here**);

Thanks

Comment: If you want to put quotes, then add them. If your printing str, then print ``"\"" + str + "\""``.

Comment: Protip: type `sout`, then do `ctrl`+`space`. This is a code template, you can edit it in IntelliJ to always include quotes as well

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.But a bit tedious. (EDITED)

ECLIPSE

1. you need to know that Ctrl+space opens options for autofill.
2. you need to create a simple template at
   Window>Preferences>Java(dropping menu)>Editor>Templates>New...
   In the open window at Name type: Syso
   at Pattern: System.out.println("")
   Make sure the checkbox Automatically insert is on.
   Apply and close
3. Now every time you type Syso and hit Ctrl+Space there will be first option
   of autofill with quotations. Profit.

oof, didn't notice about Intellij , my bad. Thought about Eclipse. Well here is one for Intellij

INTELLIJ

1. I believe the Intellij version of cntl+space is Tab button
2. Go to Settings>Editor>Live Templates
   Pick any template and press Plus icon. Choose Live Template
   In abbreviation type your desired word (I would put: Syso)
   In Template txt type : System.out.println("")
   Make sure the box with Reformat according to style is checked
3. Now every time you type Syso you can hit Enter and have PROFIT!